# How to get web application Database Status in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to show one `detail_report` page of my web application which is hosted on server.

We have used asp.net to create that application.

I have following list to show on `detail_page`

`Host Name` 
`Host Date/Time`

`Database Status`

`Build Version`
`Build Timestamp`

I'm really trying to get `Database Status` using `Ping` but unable to do that.

anyone can help me I need to use `asp.net + C#`

Comment: What's the 'database status'? Just whether it's online or not?

Comment: what are you trying to get exactly?

Comment: Yes I just want to show on my detail page `Database_Name` `Status:Connected/Disconnected`
If possible please help me in `Host Name` `Host Date/Time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try doing something like this.  Hope this helps.

```
public void displayDBDetails()
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(string yourConnectionString);
    sqlConn.Open();

    string dbName = sqlConn.Database.ToString();
    string dbStatus = sqlConn.State.ToString();
    string dbServerVersion = sqlConn.ServerVersion.ToString();
    etc.....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need to ping database in order to get status of database?

Just **handling the sql connection exception** in your application will be enough to show the related information on server status. In addition to the exception handling, when your DB is down, you may also use connection string information to display the DB name, and other information from resource files like web.config.

However, i hope you don't have plans to display username and password of the connection string to your users :)